# Generic with T of value type

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to define a generic class where T can belong only to value type (such as int, double and so on)?

Comment: Apologies, closed it off without fully reviewing the linked answers (not used to that gold badge close feature just yet!), although the question header was the same, the actual question was much different. Though I am surprised I cannot find a duplicate of this somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you need a `struct` constraint:

```
class OnlyStructs<T> where T : struct { }
```

But you should be aware of that this also allows user-defined structs, not just `int`,`double` etc.. Unfortunately there is no built-in way to restrict `T` for only specific types like `where T : int,double,float`.

Answer (score 4):

Use struct in generic constraint `where T : struct`